# how could I read the data and the image from this json file into flatlist?

Tags: react-native

Please I'm struggling to read this data of the json file on a simple flatlist, I tried to do item.content or item.description and item.medias but it doesnt work please could someone help me

```
[
    {
        "medias": [
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAALYAAACvCAYAAABQKSRXAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAAmJLR0QA/4ePzL8AAAAHdElNRQfhBAcKOBaXR3CCAAAASXRFWHRjb21tZW50AEZpbGUgc291cmNlOiBodHRwczovL2NvbW1vbnMud2lraW1lZGlhLm9yZy93aWtpL0ZpbGU6RFhDX1RlY2gucG5n4Fgx2gAAACV0RVh0ZGF0ZTpjcmVhdGUAMjAxNy0wNC0wN1QxMDo1NjoyMiswMDowMD/Nvz8AAAAldEVYdGRhdGU6bW9kaWZ5ADIwMTctMDQtMDdUMTA6NTY6MjIrMDA6MDBOkAeDAAAATXRFWHRzb2Z0d2FyZQBJbWFnZU1hZ2ljayA2LjguOS05IFExNiB4ODZfNjQgMjAxNy0wMy0xMiBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmltYWdlbWFnaWNrLm9yZ6wvQ+0AAAAYdEVYdFRodW1iOjpEb2N1bWVudDo6UGFnZXMAMaf/uy8AAAAYdEVYdFRodW1iOjpJbWFnZTo6SGVpZ2h0ADUwMHiYA+wAAAAXdEVYdFRodW1iOjpJbWFnZTo6V2lkdGgANTAw62lTsQAAABl0RVh0VGh1bWI6Ok1pbWV0eXBlAGltYWdlL3BuZz+yVk4AAAAXdEVYdFRodW1iOjpNVGltZQAxNDkxNTYyNTgywFnCLQAAABN0RVh0VGh1bWI6OlNpemUAMTIuNktCQvrONG4AACRvSURBVHhe7Z0H2BXF9cZXExQEK4INRKUoKiAaSKKiAlFiRBAV7MEeQSNqVAKKGCXG8hBjRQ0WoiEWMGoAMQFiiYWmUgUFBFsQFaSIlCT7n9/xe/e/32W/ynf3Xnb3fZ7z7L1nd2fOzLxz5sxs28rzPN9JhgyJwtYl2wwZEoWM2BkSiYzYGRKJjNgZEomM2BkSiYzYGRKJjNgZEomM2BkSiYzYGRKJ1F953HrrrU2SgP/85z8lvzJkl9QzJBKpJfZWW23l+b7vHX300d4BBxzgrV27dov03JQBu//3v/95o0aNsnKobGkHNZA6+d73vmfb0047zXHA9//73//adkuDCz9sO27cOCuPI7VJuKxplFSHIo7cniO0N3z4cO+CCy7w1q1b533/+98v2Vv8cHw2e7/66iuvbdu23ieffJJ56xBKMT1N4oZw2+63336+I4d5Pjek23ZLgLz1gAEDrByO5KXKl3KJVKZGRIaBAwcaSUSWYodCpzlz5vh169a1MmQhSCmJVKZGRIbtttvOnzt3rpFlS4i3ZWPPnj3Nfs0ZMgkkUpkqESlOOeUUI0uxEzt3wqiQKpNSEqlMnYgcY8aMMdIUa0iiOYCb6Prt2rUzmzNvHSmRytSJyHHooYcaaUAxTiTV4e655x6zN5swlimRylSKSPKHP/zByFNsXlsd7bPPPvN33313szULQ8qUSGUqRSRp2LCh//HHHxuJislrq6NdfvnlZmfmrcuVSGVqRWTp27evkahYvLYmtNOmTfNr1aplNmbLe+VKpDK1IrJA8LfeesvIVAyrJBo5unXrZvZlE8YKJVKZahFpjj/+eCNTocMRjRrPPvus2ZXF1ZWSSGXqReQZOXKkkapQIYk61Zo1a/w2bdqUsi2TciVSmXoReQ488ED/66+/NnIVwnOrQ91xxx1mTxaCVFoilZk4EYmGDBli5Irbayu2X7JkSba8V3WJVGbiRBPJ+vXr+x988IGRLM6JpPLq06eP2ZF568pLpe/Hdp6i5Ff14YhS8uv/4dotkGKEI5Pds927d2/vsccesydVaqIuKoLyeeONN7yOHTt6GzZsKNp7rbFLEoXNtbm6/OCMggveCGGodRUUeUwhRLawnThxoqvfeEISxfNdunSx/IvNW1Mf2MSyaDG1l6Rcj+0Mtp7ihmLvqaeesqc1+F8d4PW+/fZbb9WqVd6yZcvsaY8FCxZ4boj3Pv30U2/lypUlR36XrzxldfOrSeA58aBHHXWU98orr5Ro8wfKTfmffPJJ74wzzgjyLzRoF2yhTcL21KpVy9tzzz29Jk2a2POjbN2cwNt55529unXrettss03ApaqAeiCNu+++2xsxYkTAicrCGB4l6onO6LytCDiy+/Pnz/dHjx7tX3bZZX7Lli1LeSc8OKL/hRLZ8PDDD5vdGzdutG1NQ/W8evVq/6CDDiqVd6EEHoTbBNl11139k046yW7Gmjx5sv/ll1+a3TUJ1fHNN99seeqKayUlUmkiYu+22262jkqlMwzXpORi/fr1vvOKfr9+/fy99torsKPQBFdd7LPPPv7y5cvN1nx0djUmKzHkl0uoOEWEVtmd5/VPOOEE33lPf+nSpWZnuA6cN41s4+oKXAD9+/e3/Kt4b0yk0kQFYqkJzwpqujFJTxXCVjqwYsUK//777/cPPvjgwJ5wRcctIhkVDWraa6v8Cxcu9HfZZRfLq5BllSPZYYcdbGVm5syZZp/ah61IWNO8AKpfHtvDji2K2FEIkxysXbvWf+SRR/ymTZuaPVR4ITyZ6oNnDGfNmmW2he3cXFBucP7551s+hSqj8q1Tp45/8cUX+4sWLTK7AO0P4eLggYhdzYeVI5UmhSK2QF5hkruJp3/99dcHD6/SAHF7NDX6ySefbDbVFLFFasIwOi7lirtsypffnTt39qdPn2425bZDXEgssYXciqXC27dvb7YVgtwaol944QWzR6TcHKhejznmmFJ5xCXqsNtvv71/1113BWUqBKGFxBNbEMEBhb7qqqvMPkgQJxGUV9u2bWvkMTI14KOPPmrpimRxCG0swrRq1cqfPXu22YJNhSK0kBpiC1S4Kp3Ye9ttty1lbxwi8g0dOtTsqK7XVn0yUW7WrJmlGVc5yEflOPXUU4ObvShLMbRz6ogNsENkIi7lfo6wzfkW5dOgQQP/k08+MTuqUzdqvOuuu87Si8tbh0l99dVXmw3YX2gvHUYqiS2o8FOnTrX19twy5FNEDFYOQFW9tkg0b948v169epZWXB1Ttg8aNMhswPZiIjVINbGBKmDKlCnmQXPLkW+BJK+//rrZUBVyqCP06tUrSCc37XyI8gm/1q2Y2zW1xAYbNmyw7aRJk2KdSIokLI+BytaPSD1+/Hg7Py6bRY6LLrrI8i9WUoOM2CVQRTzwwAOblCWfInI//vjjlr9IWxGwV8uWcRBbdnbq1KmoXwokZMQOQZVx3nnnbVKefIlIyZVRVjdAefUk4t933312XhwhiGzkhjZNdostps7F5hA7cV8NcySxLbc67r333vY733Aktlt6Fy5c6A0dOjTQRcG1k9m4dOlS77e//a3pyjo2H7j33nu9vfbay27/dGQv0SYPiSuZG2Ws0erVq+e50MD+xwHyBHfeeaf33nvvGXmjCCvdbbfd5n322WebdY97ZSFbLrnkEq9Hjx5mqxxAkrGJG5dsiaGIoGGMe7xzy5Uv0VDJKgfIHer1/+2337ZbQHPPz4eoDd3o5S9btszy39LaMAtFQpBHGjx4sD3dEQdc7GwjxNNPP+29+OKLNtTLk4cxaNAge4YxDq+pcIM8GzRoENiYdCSW2DQejbjrrrt6V199dYk2/xCR6FDr16838jqnE8S0zz77rDd27NgySV+TUB58eMlNpk1H6JMGJJbYQB7xwgsvjG0iCZHId+rUqfY1srCObzDeeOONposD8sxXXXWV5Z/vjlRMSDSxaVgac/vtt7eJU1zAQ4Nbb701mCCC+++/35s1a5b9j5pY1iTkrXm4tmfPnoEuLUh8SeW13ITOnraPA5AWD8mT+Kx+gA8//ND73e9+Z7/j8Jwq9/nnn+9tu+22lqd0aUDiiS3P1bRpU69Tp06mi6OB5ZEfeOABb+7cubZ+vHz58liW98IjVffu3QNdmpCescnhrLPOsm0cQzLkhUysfpx22mneww8/bHomtPmGysd34lu0aGEkT1MYAlJRWnmr9u3be40aNYqtoUXuOXPmlHohUL6hEaFr1662TSNSQWyFI3vssYfXrl0708U1NIvcceUHCIN4O1Pnzp3tf5x5FwvSNT45dOjQwbb5jnPDgGhx5aeRiLVrLXFmxE4w1LiHH364beMkdpwQsdu0aWPvzGOkyoidYKhx9913X69hw4ZBiJA0aDWmdevWtk1qB64IqQtFeHtns2bN7HcSVwpE7P3339+2afTWIFUeW5MqJpHSJQkqDyEIr/IFGbFTAHmzuO72KxR22mknez81yIidIqjRkxZ/isTc0VinTh37nVakkthcagZJnVjx9JDubEwrUkns2rVrl/xKJrjpKYkT46oglaVPetyZdlKDVNZAHDciFRIbN25M7fq1kEpi8yQLSKrn/vbbb+2KY5qRSmKvWLHCtkkjtrz0119/nfhRqSKkitgi8scff2zbpOKLL74wcqcZqSE23kxLYJ9//rltkxqHEorwWBpIa6ydulBkzZo13pIlS+x30hqd8jAqEV/zujXp0ohUeWzA56751DVIYqNrVOI5S5ARO+FQA7/77ru2HMZabxIbXWWaOXOmbSF6GsmdOmLrI/9JXerTjV7Tpk3zvvrqq8SWsyKkgtiQWi+pmTx5cok2PkCuuAhGWcmLySMv55EubUgNsQENzavHgDxbvgHJlH9c5NYl9eeee862cZW1mJAqYo8ZM8YaOa64U3H8gAEDvCOOOMJ+x3Efh8o2adIk75tvvonlJT3FhsQTmwaFyBCa1/tKl29AYPI88MADvVtuucX75S9/WbIn/yBf8meEev311wNdmpB4YqtBX3rpJVspEOHiwpAhQ2zLuwO7dOlieWtJLp9Q2PPQQw/ZNm1IPLE19A8bNsy2ccS5GiFOPPFE+zQGy4vgpptusmcu43glgjovL6BniVM2pQWJJjYNCYFee+01b9y4cYEunyA/iMujWTfffLPpIBU6XrF20UUXmS7fsbZCMO5kfPDBB0u06UGiiS2vyJe8IBYNne/4WoTt27evvbSGu+zQyZaBAwd6u+22W6xee8SIEd6MGTNiD8MKicQSW8R5/vnnTeRJ8wnlwavFfv3rX5uOzgQgFSTnU3TXXHNNoMsn5LW5KUqxflqQSGKrQbnh6frrrzddvr0jEFHJkyfFIXI4X5H80ksvtXfr0QnyTW518FGjRnmjR4+2/PLdwYsBiSS2Go5lttmzZxuh8j0EizCsV/PNG6BPdAjy6DxMfMMNN5gujqVHdS7CIF4+H0d9FAOo2UhxFWLbLek7j85L2nbs2LFmv8qQT1E+yKRJkyx/2REF1WG3bt3sfEe0TdKsaVEe55xzjuVdnn3Fguw7jyXAC+GNPvroI/uYkquT2EIQ8uKLCR07djSvjB1lgWMBXpvVE47Pt52yia8V33PPPfabUCmpSAyxITUE4xKy80r2+BeNl+8hF0JCGl52qfCiIpIqbDnssMOCr5mhyzdUF3wejwtWhEpJJXciiB0mb+/evb1XX33VSA158g0R8sorr/SaN29ueVaGpCI/KySNGzeu9HmbA41gkPnMM8/03nnnncSSe4snNqSmsSDFBRdcYDN/GisuUpNPy5YtvX79+gW6ykDn8ubXa6+91nQVefqaAOSm0zOJ5ItifB8nqeTeJPCWuIq2bbFOHl1j2HbDhg3+2WefbbZWZYKxueLIadsnnnjC7JA9lYXqct26dX779u1LpZlvceS2retY/vTp080OTdaKBZszeXQSqTQpVmJjg0jkPI//05/+1OyMk9QixnHHHWd2VLdeVA5WcUhPdR6HqAw77rijP27cOLMDe9xIYr8LjVQRm0pXgd977z2/devWZmOcpFa91KpVy3/jjTfMls0hg87t1auXpSvCxSEaISjLvffea3ZgT1VHn3wgFcSWl1b+w4cPN0+DfXESAVF+ffr0MVs218Pp/JkzZ/p16tSxtOP03JBbBD/99NP9pUuXmj2F9t6JJnYuoRctWuT37NkzsC+umFSi/Bo2bOgvXrzYbKqJxpeH7N+/v6Uf5wiEUJfqsE2bNvXdJDyoc8pXCIInkthUZJjQa9as8W+55RZ/1113NZtohDi9mkSNP3ToULNLhNxcqJxffPGFv/fee1secXdaRPWKdO/e3Z89e7bZhX25bZJvJILY4Ypjq3xWrlzpDxs2zG/evLnZQmOLXHGL8j3kkEP8tWvXmn01WR/qJIRZ4fzilnAdExpdfPHF/pw5c8w2yotgq9oqX4iF2OGGrAmhQkRkNWgYeIpBgwYF3guhwgvhxSTK+7nnnjMbo+zeHFAvgHSPPPJIy6tQ5EbIWxyA4Keccoo/ZswYGz2B7KUdIaGIjoTburqSCI9N+kye7r77br9Tp07+dtttF9hBBReS0IgI1qNHD7OXxssHlO7EiRMtP7VBoYT8wwRHWrRo4V955ZX+hAkTLHTKFzaH2Fzq4kckXGHsShVXx3iRI8/r8R99VcF5rkd7GzZs8NatW2evuXUTQW/evHne9OnT7bm8999/326KF1yF2nmuM5VoCgPVA992mTJlin31FptcZys5ombhyG1l556XJ554oiiuDFIHlDfcHugaNWrktWrVyu57YetIb19l4+Yu6gvOVLeeHLHtfJ4VHTx4sP1GVxmUS2yBD2Jyn7EKVh1QGevXr7eb/7mcyzucIXkYqjzA8dXNq6YhYnHp+7bbbguIly9QbuqCl2f+4Ac/8Nw8I+hcxQDaSPbkOh303BDGgxY77rijEZz6qw5IH+7Nnz/fW7x4cZXrgCMLIs7QYKKSO9wVi2Af2yZNmvjLli1z9Zq/cCwM4lXwm9/8xvKvYnwZm4Tbj9/F0oaV8tigpjyUa6tAtgRQbjz08OHD7SarfHtrgfrBQ61atcqebsdr4SlzPWQxArsR/d5cVHf0DlieSWnBC7F1YVgwU48T8tojR44sZU8mlZJIZSZONKy+/PLLRjARLU5olYSbrbAlI3elJVKZehGBzj33XCNWIUgNROw333yzaOPsIpVIZapFnnqXXXaxe1OACFYIqFP94he/MLsyr10piVSmWkQc7k0BulBQKCi2/+STT+zmK2xT58ukTIlUpla0vHfwwQf733zzjREq7kljFNS5uPkK+zKvXaFEKlMrIvYzzzxjRCpUbJ0LdS4eI+MmrLCtmURKpDKVIi94wgknGIkKGVdHQZ2Mm7CwMyN2uRKpTJ0oZq1du7b/zjvvGIGKxVuHoc7GvdLYm4UkZUqkMnUignDXGihGUgMRe8aMGcEdkNlEMlIilakSEaNx48bB/SDFFoaEoYnkr371K7M789qREqlMlYgYekq70Mt7FUGd7vPPP/cbNWpktmdeexOJVKZGNAH70Y9+FBC6GJb3KoJsve+++8z+zGtvIpHK1Ig83fjx440oxRpb50KdD4L/+Mc/tjJkqySlJFKZCpGXO+OMM4wkkJphHtJsCcKr3cCLL74YlCkLSQKJVCZeRICdd97Z3igFinnCWBYgODjzzDOtPFlI8p1U+kGDpMERwB4auOKKK+ybMV999VW1H2EqJByx7fErnhft2rWrff7Oddot5kGOfCG1xBbq1au3xZMA++mUkNqFUyXadCP1xM6QTKSe2AzbSUHaw48wMo+dIZHY4j/VkSFDFDJiZ0gkMmJnSCQyYmdIJDJiZ0gkMmJnSCQyYmdIJDJiZ0gkMmJnSCQyYmdIJDJiZ0gkMmJnSCQyYmdIJDJiZ0gkMmJnSCQyYmdIJDJiZ0gkMmJnSCSyR8NiQvjZymJ6NrFY7dpcVJrYvIejLFAhvN8iF7nn8B6PXFCxW4e+tU06uRXM/qiHbqOOzZAB1JjHFjmjCC5AzjARRdayyFlRmpyPlJenEO4cZXXEfIIP5it/viEfd/5lIWzXxo0bI53PlohKEZvCd+7cuZRnBRCENyh9+OGH3rJly+y/3rDEB+I5Z926dV6tWrW8FStWeK+//ro1KMdRmWz32msv+xA+lVq7dm3vo48+8qZNmxakQ57777+/16FDB2/vvfc2PXlxzNSpUy19HVtsUBnr16/vvfTSS/bGpu2339678MILvb///e8Fs1t21a1b1xs/frx90J8XB1111VXeM888Yy/fScKLdyB2pLgKsO2ee+4ZvCMuF+j//e9/+08//bR/2GGH2fGuwWw7YcIEO0avvD355JNNz4c4SduR1v/HP/5h+1wD20shf/KTn9gxSPPmzf2//vWv/vr16+2YMMj33XffDb5YS1o6L0patWrld+3a1b4v4zpS5DE1Lao/PmGnL5CBcD2Ej49LZJfrZPaObcF1ONMXyq4alkiliSpg9913t4aBTJAvl+T6D4Fdrw/O32efffzPPvss2D9//nx7CaTSpSLB2rVrbXvDDTcE50I+Ogwgz1zQEQBp9+7d285RhwqLCP/YY4/Z8UBvJ+V42RI+Hn1Yco8JC/tyj1eeOs95RN+NbEE9nHjiiaZ3I+Em50jC6Wpfrm3l2VVeObR1Xtq+HSn8/Oc/N32Y2OWlEyVhu5Eo2zkm97ioNHPPyd1fgUQqTZQYxP72229Liu/706dPt8/FvfDCC/7cuXNNB6lFQH1BFrngggtMx2fcwO233256F4L4n376qemACy18N1TbPjzcggULTK9X5c6ZM8e/5557/FtvvdW+bU5eym/16tX+QQcdZOeqIiX6r68VAGxHl1tZZVUgOvbl6sur8PC+Bg0a+C4UK8m97A8j5doelrLsytWTRlnpcCz7dA7ExvEIchAaUaPKjJS1L5x2rj5XlytR522mRCpNlJmILS/Zs2dP01MBeJ2LL77YvK48Et9xadKkSZAOHQCwnw5wwAEHGMGBwhQXjwfH85FOoM4AoVWRqqQ+ffrYPp2PR0afW+Eu1rf8Ro4caccBF99aR2jdurV9JYzjlO5uu+1mHvXSSy+1DnrMMccYAcLHhH8znHfq1Mnsueyyyyzc0ddz5flyid2tWzfTcyzn9OrVy+oYneqcka1t27Ym2I+OOj3nnHMsL/Kk7sPnYJN+u3mJf9ZZZ/n9+vXzzzvvPP/QQw/13VwnOI5tWcTmOKXDp0B69OjhX3755UF9UOZwOuHfLm73O3bs6F9yySX+2Wef7bt5kekJKykLdvApb+qIUZk2QK8PRSHKmxG/TZs2JuKT9lVCIpUmSiSX2Hhh9DSciCTPrHh44MCBQTqQaNWqVaYHhCRff/110BHuvvvu4FiG7YULF5oeuAlnYAf5UenK809/+lPJUb6/ePFiOxc9x+sYyIPXVwcAeHo64po1ayz25jgEMmsUkW1sZ82a5R977LF2DA2oRqTBKYugc5YuXer37ds3SDdMbI4hBBszZoz9V51yDmTVOeeee67pwZtvvmmE/vLLL+2/8vnnP/8ZdAjZxP+//OUvwQirYyk/x+vjp0hZxKbuttlmG3/IkCGb5Al4nzhlV77Km8+dMO8BOp5yE+KovIDO3L59e/utuYdGeXU+OsSSJUsC58bX3GQb20pIpNKkLGKff/75podoKhRhxNtvv237AYREL0OvueYa04tgCiNy4+7DDz/c9ApBLrrooiAvtojyJJzBg3To0MHOw1ugDxObBgDhhgn/1kRywIAB9p99CLGnGhVQdvLiWASiKZ1wekD1dPXVV9uxjAIiNh0/7L05V2X96KOPrBNwDiQTaHzNQwDpy4EMHz48sAlPqG9UygZBNuJgNMnfYYcdygxFnnzySdOpnYRwmel8yhvPu3z5ctsXdiIA7oQdm+pl4sSJJZrvQlHlzZZRRvjiiy+CehFPKiGRSpOKiC3yyBgqWcDrhocs0ho7dqztU0OSnlZB8BBsTz/9dNunyvnhD38YpME2LOUVUvuaNm1qwygdTZg5c6Z/xRVXmBfAa+27776B52CrSRT2h8ukymeVSBNbwO9rr73Whl/mAgKN2axZM8sj3LCU++GHHzavjhcFqhPlLY+temD14vrrrzehAwiMfPLaDz30kOlE+r/97W82Cj3yyCOlRi05nVyPrXbVpF7ecurUqVZXhI/hzg7hqDvOUbipcvCfvB999NEgHeXfv39/O4eyAnWe8IrYK6+8YjrA/AhdFbw1Eqk0qSqxVbFg0aJF5hHCx7F0B1R4tvKCIjafnACqhHbt2pm+qsSW6Ly77rrL0gNPPfWU6TSayFsDPudM3E18V79+fQtV9O1HGqBFixaBN8VG5Igjjgjy22+//WxyTfhCWEN5SC9M7AceeCA4nvCJuhKYHKOXx1KjE1LpnJNOOsl0gP2MOswlwp2NjsOxahtibcDxeNujjjrK9OHlPnlsiCzQCcLx79FHHx2UGxDvUwbaUvzQl8yUN6EHULvLY5Pu+++/bzowYsQI09PmGqHC9RvFgbKkWjdBufxKfn232O8qy3PE9BwJSrSe53q25xrTLs64Anuux3uuQey3dGyHDRtmF3NIA7gQwLbKw02cbOsKZVtAnmCnnXbyWrZsace4yYld4AGuQu3iB6JjXSXaFnChBLAfHHjggbbFpuOOO85z8a43Y8YMzxHOLiq5UMn2czz5HXzwwfaffF5++WU7hn2Uh4tVjjR2QYnjuODhPGOpCzFcnAFcIKGeuCglcDEsDNL9+OOP7YKU8MEHH1jdApWBi1jOAdlv6tKRy35r/4MPPmh1y3/qxM17TK/6AZzHfueFSzSe57y9fSmBOmOf86R2UYeyAxeCWFqUnTZyDtBzo5ztQwdczO+5OVDwXyBdN+kv+ecZP+BCly5dgjaaMmWK1S9wHdK2lUG1iK3KoiAiXPfu3T03ebAriECNx38qffDgwfafc+fNm2eFgryQ8oYbbgiM5lsqNIAqwcWytmU/lSnSgptuusmbO3eu5+JKu7LnRgjTQyKJOkiYWMpL+9RIAvvDaUA+5w3tKuvKlSuDDgRWr15tWwjCeWxdOOO5EMGE8ofJA9SJnQezbbjBZVsY4XIA7A13dParTgD/ZRfpcSx5Kj+AI8oFeYigggsjbKt0gNIGahOB42lbgB2AfN1E3X7nYuTIkZ6Lze037ee8uxFbEPFz26giVIvYbvJT8us74yG1C0PsPwZQ8Mcff9z+Aze8Wk+k4ijgscce6z3//PPW4JzPpVy8HMBbuljcflMhHDto0KCAbGxppJNPPtlzw6D9h2hu+LdL7Xg8F+96LuyxY9gPwo0lYmmfm33bFnKMGjXKc5Mw8+IuPrZL/nheeSY8dNjDuqHZa9KkiaWJfdiCx8JTv/jii8EHj8L55yJM2txOAHLPDR8PKDNenU6n/27SbL/V4ahHFyYFZXZzINuGQdtBTDqycOKJJ9qW8tFJ8eaMasKCBQtM2E/ajG6UGchO2pY6VL0LdCI8+bPPPmv/OX/gwIGem1fZf5yJi9XttzpJVUDukeIqxbaKsQUug995552+G9781157zWIrZ3QQQ7ECojQUj2pCw+QHvSNOqdUBN+QEa8pMSBQvEmOBV1991ZYQmfQRIzMhIV+EY/QRT5aoAHpXUcEl9/AFGmLfn/3sZ7beSnxITCdwhZAVFs5BWP1gue1f//qXrX+jc41Uat3+rbfesokPse6f//xn05E/OPLIIzeJsbWO7RrWtqQt/P73vzedYmzAUiYrK+gRViC4KAXIh3KgD3+ElUmwGyUtPuU6Q/gKowuXLL5FwnE5eZLOjTfeaP816WNOQEzOrQBaziNf2lsrLCqDeHDddddZPbKqpThebakYW/MqbATUJ0IawIWptt91bNtWUSKVJiI2lUpFqjBq0DCku+OOO4LzWT1gBq9GZjmQZUHnGW0/hQdakdBsGYGQajwVNAzSVJ66jO88jj9p0iTTsVoA1JE006eDcZ4aTRPh8CV3zqXzQmgaQ/aHL/nffPPNplNjYaPSVCfWJJH6YzVB5dAldRE7vAKg+guvY7PCpIs+CBNalY+8RGwIL73yku38V33pm5BMOJ2nD/RakSEvJsBA5VN9I9JpootA/Nw8w+eyT3oRGx6ItFod4hzZI2clvlRRIpUmInZ5N0EBiEnjHH/88Xa8jNUNTiqwlnMgIFuWm9wkzfap4sJXIFnqwxOUlTdeSI2hNKk0Abu0XEiHYvkLqKKBvBRLeyxNgdz8qGyIzHGqE7Yuxg9IHD6H3y4UC1YTGPGwRcewpIlexH7jjTdMDxgF0bF0KLAkx5o9eoSRITyCalRCGCH0QVblpy3Lc6ovhFWr8KoIKxzoKRsXSES23HQoM/Whdhbx6LB0FBAmtwslbWQXwsTWuaeeeqrtU2fQkiS2qM6rIgR0/IiES9DiJGaovXr1shiM/4IrqAX+rB4wIXRksTjVFcpu1TzttNMsviTmc8O/N2bMmCBNbYldXc+02bQjl00GXYVaXqTHJMcNVRanNWrUyOJNYkBWCSZMmGDxvvIUnEfy2rdv740ePdpzFWrnYCvxr+t83iGHHGLpEsMzeZk/f36QhiOGTV7Ii3NY5cBuNwQH6QD9ZiWIOLRp06ZmMxNfVg1ch7TjKCP59uzZ0/LkGGJv4nSlQUzqnIfVCflMnjzZa9GihcXvnM+chViTOgLMATiHGJX9pEc8qjKwWkQ5qVdiXtepbIJNGuHjON8RylaMsMuNdrbiov3ouPW4U6dO3h577GExNvupj9mzZ5eqD4GyYrcL76ztmZNwLKspLC4ANzJ7t99+u+VDmWnnxo0be25Et1togevYtpIjW6qDUkyvrrhCVjhkuEJs8j9XFxbSRKL2SXL3h9MLp19RXuwrLy/2hc+v6vFxSUX5lmdzWCpKh7bWftcBzINzIYiQTnMU8YHQJhzjE/Nrv45h7iRwewFRAvrK2hshkcpNBAMoQJSUlXn4HBUgVzi3orRUAexD9L+sig8fH9ZzfHhfVBraj17H5KYTlvAx4fRzj0OnMkblmVt+jpEuNz3lo/256Wm/bArbGD4OKS8d7UfKSkfnMKEXmJxz3zs3UHHl9Y9//KPpmZ8572s3PXEOiwTcJ0RnIFRTGMJNb8pb+VRDIpWZZFIpEclZKQrH68TheGmtfGlOE77hjZvjIDuA8IBz6BDsj+poVZBIZSaZVFpEbu7YY1lWq0MCpIX0LD/K+3M8t9ayioOn5k5LJtHy5lGjS1Wk3MljhgyVhSOiTSQdcb02bdrYxSAWHZgYcsWWSTEX0Byp7XjHd1tUYPGA4ziGq85MUDmG/ZuDjNgZagyQG+SulAiQnn1lkbai86uCjNgZahwQVCQFELksQnOcPHRNEFrIiJ0hkSj7zpwMGbZgZMTOkEB43v8Bsk6/fP4dm60AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
        ],
        "description": "ccc",
        "id": 3,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "user",
            "prenom": "user",
            "tel": "2126548390",
            "url": null,
            "departement": "RH",
            "username": "admin"
        },
        "content": "cccc"
    }
]
```

and this is my code (I want to display the image too )

```
 <FlatList
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        data={this.state.data}
        refreshing={this.state.isLoading}
        onRefresh={this.makeRemoteRequest}
        renderItem={({ item, index })=>
    <View>
                {item.published == true ? <Card>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onRemove}>
          <Animated.View style={rowStyles}>

            <View>
              <Text style={styles.email}>{item.data[0].content}</Text>
            </View>

          </Animated.View>
          <Animated.View style={rowStyles}>

                        <Text style={styles.email}>{item.description}</Text>
                        </Animated.View>


        </TouchableOpacity></Card> : <Text></Text> }

    </View>
}


        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}

      />
```

Comment: where do you get ```published``` value as refer in ```item.published == true```?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `keyExtractor` expects a return of `string` and you are supplying an int (id);
You could either change your id in the data store to a string if possible, or do a map to convert the id to a string or you could do this:

```
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
```

which I don't recommend because it will always be rerun on render.

Also if the data from json is not changing, you could put it on the class as shown below:
The choices are yours but I believe the `keyExtractor` is your major issue.

```js
// read the json file on import
const jsonData = require('path/to/file.json');

// set the data on mount to convert id to string
this.dataWithStringId = jsonData.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      id: item.id.toString(),
}));

render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            data={this.dataWithStringId}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <Card>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <View>
                    <View>
                      <Text>{item.content}</Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <Animated.View>
                    <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                  </Animated.View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </Card>
            )}
      />
    )
}
```

EDIT:
here is a [link to keyExtrctor](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#keyextractor)

Comment: Try the solution above directly and lets see, first log your data so be sure it is fetched from the json file. And also. how are you fetching it?

Comment: Im working with an api .. trying to get data from axios

Comment: So your data is not coming from a file as stated in the question? That doesn't change much though, my previous comment still stands to try